# How to split string into rows with space delimiter in Bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm having a hard time understanding regular expression.

I have a table mydataset.city

```
id | city
---+----------------------------------------------    
1  | LOS ANGELES&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;NEW YORK&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;INDIANAPOLIS
```

Between each cities contain 5 spaces as delimiter.

And I want it to split them into rows like this:

```
id | city
---+------------
1  | LOS ANGELES
1  | NEW YORK
1  | INDIANAPOLIS
```

How can I write this in bigquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below

```
select id, city
from your_table, unnest(split(city, '     ')) city
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]